# How to return file stat info in FUSE readdir call?

Tags: python, fuse

I have implemented a FUSE filesystem, and now I'm trying to optimize performance, as the wait time of directories with many thousands of files runs into seconds.

Some logging has shown me that after I return the list of file names, `getattr` is then called once for each file (10,000 times for my test directory of 10,000 files), with the result that a 5 second wait time is quadrupled into a 20 second wait time.

The version of FUSE I'm using [1] appears to support returning a list of tuples `(name, stat, offset)` as well as a list of names, so I tried returning

```
(
  '<file_name>',
  <stat with st_atime, st_mtime, st_mode, st_uid, st_gid, st_size>,
  0,
)
```

for each file, but `getattr` is still being called once for each file.

Anybody know what I am missing in the `stat` that is causing the O/S to still call `getattr`, or is there nothing I can do to change this behavior?

[1]

> Copyright (c) 2008 Giorgos Verigakis
>
> `__version__` = '1.1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the number of times getattr is called is beyond your control.  Depending on your implementation, you can improve performance by caching the result within getattr.